# enyim and memcached : NOT_STORED errors

Tags: memcached

We are using memcached 1.2.4 via enyim and are finding it difficult to get some objects to cache.  If I watch the memcache console it just says 'NOT_STORED'.

I think we need to use [serializable] but that doesnt always work.  I cant find any documentation or relevant google hits.

Any one here got any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks and sorry for the late reply.

The problem was two-fold.  Using [Serializable] was not adequate for some objects so we have to implement ISerializable.  We were also using ADD rather than SET.

From memory I couldn't find an upgrade for memcached and once we fixed the above it worked.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Strongly recommend upgraded your version of memcached.

NOT_STORED means just that, your data was not stored.  If you are using the `add` command to store data, this means that there's already data under that key.  If you are using `replace` it means that there's *not* data under that key.  You probably mea `set`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to...I was running something like:

```
var = CACHE.fetch("key_name",1.day,true) do
  ModelName.find_by_id(id)
end
```

So I was having active record find a record for me but I didn't know that memcached doesn't store nil values. What was happening was active record was returning nil because it couldn't find the record and therefore I was telling memcache to store a nil value. The fix was simply this:

```
var = CACHE.fetch("key_name",1.day,true) do
  ModelName.find_by_id(id) || ""
end
```

I use Ruby to code with. Hope this helps.